# Is uniform noise present in some real processes?

Tags: filters, noise

Is noise with uniform distribution present in some real-life applications?

It seems that most of the internet sources describe uniform noise as something theoretical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when a real value $x$ from a sensor is discretized ($x_Q$) with a uniform quantizer, the error $x-x_Q$ is **likely** to be uniformly distributed.

Caveat: as commented by @bone, this can be stated in precise terms, see for instance:

- [A necessary and sufficient condition for quantization errors to be uniform and white](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TASSP.1977.1162977),A. Sripad and D. Snyder, 1977

> In this paper, a necessary and sufficient condition is given to model
>   the output of a quantizer as an infinite-precision input and an
>   additive, uniform, white noise. The statistical properties of the
>   quantization error are studied, and a detailed analysis for Gaussian
>   distributed inputs is given.

- Statistical Theory of Quantization, Bernard Widrow, Istvan Kollar,  Ming-Chang Liu, 1996

> The effect of uniform quantization can often be modeled by an additive
>   noise that is uniformly distributed, uncorrelated with the input
>   signal, and has a white spectrum. This paper surveys the theory behind
>   this model, and discusses the conditions of its validity. The
>   application of the model to floating-point quantization is
>   demonstrated.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the quantization error is not a random signal if the input is known. It is modeled as uniform noise because it simplifies the analysis and gives good enough results.

Comment: You notice that I wrote "likely" to make it short (now put in bold).I have now added some references.